# Как используется hashCode в HashSet/HashMap?

Tags: java, хеширование, java-hashmap, hashcode, hashset

В лекции JavaRush «[Реализации интерфейса Set, Queue](https://javarush.ru/quests/lectures/questcollections.level06.lecture09)» говорится следующее:

> Использование hash-кодов позволяет довольно быстро искать, добавлять и удалять элементы из множества (Set).
>
> Чтобы объекты твоих классов можно было класть в Set и правильно находить их там, у твоего класса должны быть правильно реализованы методы `hashCode` & `equals`.
>
> И тот и другой активно используются внутри `HashSet`/`HashMap`.
>
> Если ты забудешь реализовать метод `hashCode()`, то рискуешь, что твой объект в коллекции Set не будет найден, даже если он там есть.

У меня возникли вопросы:

1. Как понять использование hash-кодов позволяет быстро искать, добавлять и тд. Мы если помещаем в реализацию HashSet несколько значений и выводим мы видим их текстовое представление, а не hash-коды поэтому не понятно, объясните.
2. Можете привести пример, а то не очень понятно вот эта часть:

> Если ты забудешь реализовать метод `hashCode()`, то рискуешь, что твой
>   объект в коллекции Set не будет найден, даже если он там есть.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте рассмотрим пример плохой реализации `hashCode`:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        BadHash one = new BadHash();
        one.hash = 1;
        HashSet<BadHash> s = new HashSet<>();
        s.add(one);
        one.hash = 2;
        System.out.println(s.contains(one)); //false
        System.out.println(s); //2
        s.add(one);
        System.out.println(s.size()); //2
    }
}

class BadHash {
    public int hash;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return hash+"";
    }
}
```

Мы создали класс (`BadHash`) хеш которого можно изменять. В результате, после того как хеш изменился объект, ранее добавленный в `HashSet`, не удалось найти.

Что произошло по шагам:

- при добавлении элемента `HashSet` рассчитал его хеш (на тот момент 1) и поместил его в соответствующую хешу ячейку;
- при вызове `contains` `HashSet` рассчитал хеш переданного элемента (теперь 2), попытался найти его в ячейке, соответствующей 2 и не нашел;
- при выводе множества в строку он вывел то, что вернул `toString()` (2), т.е. объект все еще лежит в ячейке 1, но его хеш и строковое представление изменились;
- более того, если снова добавить тот же объект в множество, то он будет добавлен и в разных ячейках (с хешем 1 и 2) лежат ссылки на один и тот же объект.

Теперь по вопросам:

> 1. Как понять использование hash-кодов позволяет быстро искать, добавлять и тд. Мы если помещаем в реализацию HashSet несколько значений и выводим мы видим их текстовое представление, а не hash-коды поэтому не понятно, объясните.

Когда Вы выводите объекты, Вы выводите их текстовое представление. Но `HashSet` текстовое представление в расчет не берет. Множество использует `hashcode` для определения ячейки (скорости) и `equals` для проверки на совпадение.

> 2. Если ты забудешь реализовать метод hashCode(), то рискуешь, что твой объект в коллекции Set не будет найден, даже если он там есть.

Вот здесь мне не совсем понятно, что имено люди на JavaRush имели ввиду, поэтому объясню поподробнее что происходит.

Если в классе не переопределить («реализовать», имхо, не очень подходит) метод `hashCode`, то он унаследует `hashCode` от ближайшего класса-родителя в котором метод переопределен. Если ни один из классов в иерархии не переопределит `hashCode`, то будет использоваться метод класса [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()).

Проблемы могут возникнуть если логика хеша класса-родителя не подходит к Вашему классу.

Давайте снова рассмотрим пример. Объявим класс `Point` который будет обозначать точку в декартовой системе координат. Переопределим для него метод `equals`, чтобы точки с одинаковыми координатами считались одинаковыми, но не будем переопределять `hashCode`:

```
class Point {
    int X;
    int Y;

    Point(int x, int y) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Point other = (Point) o;
        return X==other.X && Y ==other.Y;
    }
}
```

Проверим, что `equals` работает корректно:

```
Point one = new Point(1, 1);
Point anotherOne = new Point(1, 1);
System.out.println("Are points equals to each other: "+one.equals(anotherOne)); //true
```

Все нормально. А теперь проверим, будет ли `HashSet` работать с `Point` без переопределения `hashCode`:

```
HashSet<Point> s = new HashSet<>();
s.add(one);
System.out.println("Can you find the point without hashCode: "+s.contains(anotherOne)); //false
```

Из-за того что `hashCode` не переопределен используется метод [`Object.hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()). Этот метод возвращает (по крайней мере пытается) разные хеши для разных объектов. В результате `HashSet` не может найти вторую точку по хешу, хотя равная ей точка уже есть в множестве.

Для того, чтобы точки корректно находились в множестве нужно:

- рассчитывать `hashCode` на основе значимых полей — так он будет совпадать для одинаковых объектов и отличаться для большинства разных;
- сделать поля неизменяемыми — так мы не пострадаем от изменений хеша.

```
class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Point other = (Point) o;
        return x==other.x && y ==other.y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(x, y);
    }
}
```

Такой класс уже будет хорошо работать с `HashSet` и `HashMap`

Comment: Отличный ответ, возьму на заметку.